# how to continue to receive GCM notification when app killed from app tray in Ionic 2

Tags: android, cordova, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am a newbie in Ionic 2, I have developed an app where I use FCM push notification in Android, and I am able to receive notification when app is in foreground or in background. But I am not able to receive notification when app is removed from background. Is there a way to run `gcmListenerService` & `gcmBroadcastReceiver` from `cordova` as the native plugin broadcaster does not serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using Service in android native code implementation. You can either create a plugin for your app for doing your task in background or can refer to [this plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) and check if it is helpful in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your response Shubham. But I already tried using that plugin,and it only works until app is not killed from the app tray.